# VBA Re-formating loop

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am having trouble creating this loop for my macro. I have it all hard coded in and it works. But if I get a longer list it will fall short. So, I am trying to reformat this list of bins. Right now when we create our list it uploads it all in one column. I would like to have a loop that will cut 22 rows from A column and paste it in next column over only utilizing columns A,B,C. And then repeat. Attaches is a horrible illustration and below is the hard code I have right now from the record macro function.

```
    ActiveCell.Offset(22, 0).Range("A1:A22").Select

    Selection.Cut

    ActiveCell.Offset(-22, 1).Range("Data[[#Headers],[Code_Bin]]").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    ActiveCell.Offset(44, -1).Range("A1:A22").Select

    Selection.Cut

    ActiveCell.Offset(-44, 2).Range("Data[[#Headers],[Code_Bin]]").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    ActiveCell.Offset(66, -2).Range("A1:A22").Select

   Selection.Cut

    ActiveCell.Offset(-44, 0).Range("Data[[#Headers],[Code_Bin]]").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    ActiveCell.Offset(66, 0).Range("A1:A22").Select

    Selection.Cut

    ActiveCell.Offset(-66, 1).Range("Data[[#Headers],[Code_Bin]]").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    ActiveCell.Offset(88, -1).Range("A1:A22").Select

    Selection.Cut

    ActiveCell.Offset(-88, 2).Range("Data[[#Headers],[Code_Bin]]").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A133:A154").Select

    Selection.Cut

    Range("A45").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A155:A176").Select

    Selection.Cut

    Range("B45").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A177:A198").Select

    Selection.Cut

    Range("C45").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A199:A220").Select

    Selection.Cut

    Range("A67").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A221:A242").Select

    Selection.Cut

    Range("B67").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A243:A264").Select

    Selection.Cut

    Range("C67").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A265:A286").Select

    Selection.Cut

    Range("A89").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A287:A308").Select

    Selection.Cut

    Range("B89").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A309:A330").Select

    Selection.Cut

    Range("C89").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A331:A352").Select

    Selection.Cut

    Range("A111").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A353:A374").Select

    Selection.Cut

    Range("B111").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A375:A396").Select

    Selection.Cut

    Range("C111").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A397:A418").Select

    Selection.Cut

    Range("A133").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A419:A440").Select

    Selection.Cut

    Range("B133").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A441:A462").Select

    Selection.Cut

    Range("C133").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A463:A484").Select

    Selection.Cut

    Range("A155").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A485:A506").Select

    Selection.Cut

    Range("B155").Select

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Selection.Copy

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("C165").Select

    Range("A485:A505").Select

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Selection.Cut

    Range("B155").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A506").Select

    Selection.Cut

    Range("B176").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A507:A528").Select

    Selection.Cut

    Range("C155").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A529:A550").Select

    Selection.Cut

    Range("A177").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A551:A572").Select

    Selection.Cut

    Range("B177").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

   Range("A573:A594").Select

    Selection.Cut

    Range("C177").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A595:A616").Select

    Selection.Cut

    Range("A199").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A617:A638").Select

    Selection.Cut

    Range("B199").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A639:A660").Select

    Selection.Cut

    Range("C199").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A661:A682").Select

    Selection.Cut

    Range("A221").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A683:A704").Select

    Selection.Cut

    Range("B221").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A705:A726").Select

    Selection.Cut

    Range("C221").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A727:A748").Select

    Selection.Cut

    Range("A243").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A749:A770").Select

    Selection.Cut

    Range("B243").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A771:A792").Select

    Selection.Cut

    Range("C243").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A793:A814").Select

    Selection.Cut

    Range("A265").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A815:A836").Select

    Selection.Cut

    Range("B265").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A837:A858").Select

    Selection.Cut

    Range("C265").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A859:A880").Select

    Selection.Cut

    Range("A287").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A881:A902").Select

    Selection.Cut

    Range("B287").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A903:A924").Select

    Selection.Cut

    Range("C287").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A925:A946").Select

    Selection.Cut

    Range("A309").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A947:A968").Select

    Selection.Cut

    Range("B309").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A969:A990").Select

    Selection.Copy

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Selection.Cut

    Range("C309").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A991:A1012").Select

    Selection.Cut

    Range("A331").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A1013:A1034").Select

    Selection.Cut

    Range("B331").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A1035:A1056").Select

    Selection.Cut

    Range("C331").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A1057:A1078").Select

    Selection.Cut

    Range("A353").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A1079:A1100").Select

    Selection.Cut

    Range("B353").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A1101:A1122").Select

    Selection.Cut

    Range("C353").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A1123:A1144").Select

    Selection.Cut

    Range("A375").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

 

End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0ZZ1.png)

Comment: Please replace the image of the code with text. While the illustration showing using arrows to annotate the rows that you want to move from one place to another might be helpful it's better that you also add a textual description of that.

Comment: Updated. That's for the feedback

Comment: Your desired output is not clear to me from your screenshot, but it seems this would be a trivial task in Power Query, available in Excel 2010+

Answer (score 0):

Always try to rewrite recorded code.

Get rid of `.Select` and of `Selection.`

```
    Range("A177:A198").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("C45").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
```

is same as

```
    Range("A177:A198").Cut Range("C45")
```

Here is some example code to help you rewrite your code.

Single-step through the first macro using F8 to see how it works

```vba
Sub Macro1()

    Range("A1:Z100").Value = Null                           ' clear destination range
    
    Stop ' single step this code by pressing F8
    
    b = 0                                                   ' destination column pointer
    
    x = 6                                                   ' size of the data "blocks"
    
    For a = 0 To 100 Step x
        Range("A1").Offset(a, 0).Resize(x).Select           ' this is only for debugging for visually verifying that the correct range
        Range("C1").Offset(3, b).Resize(x).Select           ' is being accessed. it has no effect on the movement of values between cells
        
        Range("e1").Select                                  ' select out of way cell
        
        Range("A1").Offset(a, 0).Resize(x).Value = a        ' cells do not need to be selected
        Range("C1").Offset(3, b).Resize(x).Value = a
        
        b = b + 1                                           ' point to next column
    Next a
    
End Sub
```

This macro does the copying.
Read the comments for explanations.

```vba
Sub copyRanges()

    Range("A1:Z22").Value = Null                    ' clear destination range
    
    Range("A1").Value = 0                           ' fill source range with test data
    Range("A1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:A1000"), Type:=xlFillSeries

    b = 0                                           ' destination column number
    x = 13                                          ' length of data blocks
    
    Stop                                            ' use F8 to single-step through rest of code
    
    For a = 0 To 100 Step x
        
        Range("C1").Offset(3, b).Resize(x).Value = Range("A1").Offset(a, 0).Resize(x).Value    ' this assigns values (does not do any "copy" function)
        
'       Range("A1").Offset(a, 0).Resize(x).Cut Range("C1").Offset(3, b)                        ' this copies formatting also, but is slow
        
        b = b + 1                                   ' point to next destination column
    
    Next a
    
    Range("A1:A1000").Value = Null                  ' clear source data
    
End Sub
```